# Java: Standards to use constant.equals(variable)

Tags: java, string

Which is better way and why?

```
 private final String CONSTANT_STRING = "CONSTANT"
```

which of following shall be used as per Java Official standard?

```
       public void method(String a){
           if(CONSTANT_STRING.equals(a)){
           
       }
```

or

```
       public void method(String a){
           if(a.equals(CONSTANT_STRING)){
           
       }
```

Comment: Perhaps neither -- `Objects.equals(a, CONSTANT_STRING)` won't throw a NullPointerException

Comment: CONSTANT_STRING.equals(a) will never throw a NullPointerException and that is why it is recommended.

Comment: You might also use `(a != null && a.equals(CONSTANT_STRING))` if you want null checks to be obvious to the reader.

Comment: Although this question is POB, no?

Comment: There is no official Java standard that says you need to use one or the other.

Comment: "as per Java Official standard" there is no official Java standard one way or the other: the semantics of the two expressions are different, so the one you choose depends on the semantics you require. _Not_ throwing an NPE can hide problems, for example if you don't expect `a` to be null.